# why this sql not working?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a query

```
public static function TestQuery(

 $start=0,
 $limit=0){


 $sql = "
SELECT     count(*) AS total
FROM    db.table1
JOIN    db.table2
 ON     table1.fieldID = {$fieldID}

AND    table2.assigned = 'N'";



  $qry = new SQLQuery;
  $qry->query($sql);
  if($row = $qry->fetchRow()){
   $total = intval($row->total);
  }

 return $total;

}
```

which works fine but when I add the limit as below, then it doesnt work and gives me errors

```
public static function TestQuery(

 $start=0,
 $limit=0){


 $sql = "
SELECT     count(*) AS total
FROM    db.table1
JOIN    db.table2
 ON     table1.fieldID = {$fieldID}

AND    table2.assigned = 'N'";

//this fails   
if($recordlimit > 0) $sql .= "LIMIT {$startRecord}, {$recordLimit} ";  
//  
  $qry = new SQLQuery;
  $qry->query($sql);
  if($row = $qry->fetchRow()){
   $total = intval($row->total);
  }

 return $total;

}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Put a space in front of LIMIT:

```
" LIMIT {$startRecord}, {$recordLimit} "
```

without the space you sql will result in a syntax error.

**Edit:** This is answer is not correct! MySQL will not error without a space before LIMIT (however, earlier versions of phpmyadmin will incorrectly parse such sql).

Comment: @webbiedave: Not for me. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Mark Byers: Whoops. Guess what? Error is being caused by earlier versions of phpmyadmin and not mysql!

Comment: @webbiedave: Never mind. Error or no error, I still think having the space there is much better style.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables are called $limit and $start:

```
if($limit > 0) $sql .= " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit} ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
if($recordlimit > 0) $sql .= "LIMIT {$startRecord}, {$recordLimit} ";
```

To

```
if($recordlimit > 0) $sql .= " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit} ";
```

It looks like your SQL is getting squished together and should be getting a bad syntax error, and you had the wrong (seemingly) variable names in there.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong variables

```
if($recordlimit > 0) $sql .= "LIMIT {$startRecord}, {$recordLimit} ";
```

Solved
Thanks

Comment: If Mark Byers answer is correct, you should accept it. Although I think my and manyxcxi changes are also necessary to get it working.

Comment: Please don't post follow-up comments to your question as answers. Also, if an answer provided your solution, please accept it.